# OnClick suddenly not working on Google Sites in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, google-sites

I wrote a page that used buttons with onclick to call a function as part of a set of practice problems and answers for my students.  It has worked since July with no issues through Friday, September 5 at least.  Today the buttons fail to function at all in Chrome, and I can't figure out why for the life of me.  They do continue to function properly in IE.

I've posted the simplest code I could write that won't work below.  It's awfully simple, and honestly I think it's fine.  It seems to work if I paste the entire thing into JSFiddle's HTML box, but if I try to separate the script it doesn't do anything.  I don't know whether that's because it's broken or because I am separating it incorrectly though.

I'm having trouble trying to debug it, largely because Google Sites completely rewrites your work into its own format which is more or less unreadable without being made of silicon.  When I load this and try to click, I do get an exception:

```
Uncaught Error: shouldn't happen: ES5/3 object passed to makeDOMAccessible
```

But I have had absolutely no luck with figuring out what is happening there, or whether that is even really the problem or not.

I've read a lot about Google Sites being picky with Javascript, and I don't know whether the issue is with Sites or Chrome or the two together or what, but it's something that I'd like to get sorted out, as the bulk of my students and I primarily use Chrome.

All of the code below is going into an inserted HTML box as written, just FYI.

Apologies if this turns out to be a duplicate; I searched for quite a while and couldn't find a solution.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="Check()">Push Me</button>

<script>
function Check() {
    alert("It worked");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions for fixing what I've got (if it's even broken) or redoing it in a straightforward way that would work with Sites and Chrome would be welcome.  Thanks in advance.

[Here is one full page that was working previously in Chrome and is no longer](https://sites.google.com/a/sheridan-schools.org/ap_chemistry_2014/resources/units/unit-01---stoichiometry/unit-01-2---limiting-reactants-and-percent-yield).  It displayed the rows of a table as you pressed the various buttons.

EDIT: This appears to work in older versions of Chrome.  I guess I need to hit up the Chrome forums with this issue.

Comment: not sure if i'm testing the right thing but i get rows when clicking buttons (34.0.1847.116/Linux)

Comment: Yes, it would be the buttons at the bottom of the linked page that give rows when you click.  You're using Chrome as well?  It didn't work for at least two dozen people at my school today or for me on a completely separate machine at home tonight.  (And I tried it using a non-admin login, via the Incognito window.)

Comment: yes, i'm on chrome. all buttons work for me (adding rows for initial,change,ending) and the check question buttons work too

Comment: That's really odd.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: I see the error in version 37.0.2062.103 on windows

Comment: Try to not use inline events, use addEventListener and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried changing the name of your function from Check to something else?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, it fails with every function name I've tried.  I just picked Check as the example function here.  The actual page uses AnswerProblem as the function name.

Comment: upgraded to 37.0.2062.94/Linux and i see the error too now

Answer (score 2):

The workaround suggested by epascarello, using addEventListener in place of onclick events, seems to work. I still can't get the alert window in my example to work for some reason (against Sites policy?), but the actual functionality I wanted, setting the innerHTML of a paragraph object, is working properly.

This appears to be an issue between Google Sites and Chrome v.37.  Hopefully it is resolved in the near future.

Here is an example of equivalent code that is working correctly.

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="AnswerButton1">Check Answer 1</button>

<p id="Answer1"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("AnswerButton1").addEventListener("click",function(){Answer(1);});

    function Answer(n){
        document.getElementById("Answer"+n).innerHTML = "Answer to Number 1";
    }  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to those who helped.