# onClick Not Functioning in Chrome in Google Sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, google-sites

I'm using a zippy folder imbedded in a html box in Google Sites. It had been functioning properly for many months on all browsers. Now, all of a sudden, it fails in Google Chrome. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/9bv78cgg/3/.

Anyone have any suggestions? I know that Google Sites is tricky, but I find it odd that this would suddenly stop functioning in Chrome.

Many thanks!

```
<div style="width:680px">
<div class="zippy" onClick='document.getElementById("ui2").style.display = ((document.getElementById("ui2").style.display=="block") ? "none" : "block");'> <span class="link"><img src="http://entstatic.appspot.com/images/common/zippy_plus.png" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp; Can one person have multiple email addresses?</span> </div>                  
                  <div class="content" id="ui2" style="DISPLAY: none"><p>Yes. You can give each person multiple email addresses by creating email aliases for them. You can add up to 30 email aliases per person.</p>                  
</div>                  
                             <div class="zippy" onClick='document.getElementById("ui4").style.display = ((document.getElementById("ui4").style.display=="block") ? "none" : "block");'> <span class="link"><img src="http://entstatic.appspot.com/images/common/zippy_plus.png" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;Can I delegate my inbox to an assistant?</span> </div>                   
                   <div class="content" id="ui4" style="DISPLAY: none">
                     <p>Yes. You can grant your assistant access to your inbox. They can then send and reply to your email messages on your behalf.</p>                   



</div>
```

Comment: Btw, I'm able to embed this in a Google Gadget and have it function, but I'd much prefer to keep this in an HTML box. Thx!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, use event listeners instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736009/onclick-suddenly-not-working-on-google-sites-in-chrome